# Unable to start Kestrel on Azure App Services throws Unable to configure HTTPS endpoint expception

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-web-app-service

My application is deployed to **Azure App Service** running **dotnet core 3.1.2**. (Extension is installed)

When connecting to the Kudo console and run `dotnet Reporting.API.dll` the output is:

```
dotnet Reporting.API.dll
[09:53:21 DBG] Hosting starting
[09:53:25 INF] Azure Web Sites environment detected. Using 'D:\home\ASP.NET\DataProtection-Keys' as key repository; keys will not be encrypted at rest.
[09:53:25 INF] Starting the processing server.
[09:53:25 DBG] Reading data from file 'D:\home\ASP.NET\DataProtection-Keys\key-9d61e53e-50f6-48c2-9fb1-76edd2ec884c.xml'.
[09:53:25 DBG] Reading data from file 'D:\home\ASP.NET\DataProtection-Keys\key-9f563cfe-7cea-4332-8010-c2e0c485ee39.xml'.
[09:53:25 DBG] Reading data from file 'D:\home\ASP.NET\DataProtection-Keys\key-a4632346-de3c-4726-b84d-067511ba48de.xml'.
[09:53:25 DBG] Reading data from file 'D:\home\ASP.NET\DataProtection-Keys\key-cbf59895-b970-4cbf-aad1-eb4387edb6ab.xml'.
[09:53:25 DBG] Reading data from file 'D:\home\ASP.NET\DataProtection-Keys\key-f5be7258-dbc8-4f36-8f3e-930073d353b2.xml'.
[09:53:25 DBG] Found key {9d61e53e-50f6-48c2-9fb1-76edd2ec884c}.
[09:53:25 DBG] Found key {9f563cfe-7cea-4332-8010-c2e0c485ee39}.
[09:53:25 DBG] Found key {a4632346-de3c-4726-b84d-067511ba48de}.
[09:53:25 DBG] Found key {cbf59895-b970-4cbf-aad1-eb4387edb6ab}.
[09:53:25 DBG] Found key {f5be7258-dbc8-4f36-8f3e-930073d353b2}.
[09:53:25 DBG] Considering key {a4632346-de3c-4726-b84d-067511ba48de} with expiration date 2020-05-26 16:44:50Z as default key.
[09:53:25 DBG] Opening CNG algorithm 'AES' from provider 'null' with chaining mode CBC.
Unhandled exception.[09:53:25 DBG] Opening CNG algorithm 'SHA256' from provider 'null' with HMAC.
[09:53:25 DBG] Using key {a4632346-de3c-4726-b84d-067511ba48de} as the default key.
[09:53:25 DBG] Key ring with default key {a4632346-de3c-4726-b84d-067511ba48de} was loaded during application startup.
[09:53:25 DBG] Failed to locate the development https certificate at 'null'.
[09:53:25 DBG] Unable to locate an appropriate development https certificate.
[09:53:25 FTL] Unable to start Kestrel.
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to configure HTTPS endpoint. No server certificate was specified, and the default developer certificate could not be found or is out of date.
To generate a developer certificate run 'dotnet dev-certs https'. To trust the certificate (Windows and macOS only) run 'dotnet dev-certs https --trust'.
For more information on configuring HTTPS see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=848054.
        at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ListenOptionsHttpsExtensions.UseHttps(ListenOptions listenOptions, Action`1 configureOptions)
        at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ListenOptionsHttpsExtensions.UseHttps(ListenOptions listenOptions)
        at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.AddressesStrategy.BindAsync(AddressBindContext context)
        at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.BindAsync(IServerAddressesFeature addresses, KestrelServerOptions serverOptions, ILogger logger, Func`2 createBinding)
        at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServer.StartAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
[09:53:25 DBG] Hosting shutdown
[09:53:25 INF] Queued Hosted Service is stopping.
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to configure HTTPS endpoint. No server certificate was specified, and the default developer certificate could not be found or is out of date.
To generate a developer certificate run 'dotnet dev-certs https'. To trust the certificate (Windows and macOS only) run 'dotnet dev-certs https --trust'.
For more information on configuring HTTPS see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=848054.
        at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ListenOptionsHttpsExtensions.UseHttps(ListenOptions listenOptions, Action`1 configureOptions)
        at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ListenOptionsHttpsExtensions.UseHttps(ListenOptions listenOptions)
        at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.AddressesStrategy.BindAsync(AddressBindContext context)
        at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.AddressBinder.BindAsync(IServerAddressesFeature addresses, KestrelServerOptions serverOptions, ILogger logger, Func`2 createBinding)
        at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServer.StartAsync[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHost.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.RunAsync(IWebHost host, CancellationToken token, String startupMessage)
        at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.RunAsync(IWebHost host, CancellationToken token, String startupMessage)
        at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.RunAsync(IWebHost host, CancellationToken token)
        at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.Run(IWebHost host)
        at Reporting.API.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\agent-02\_work\35\s\src\Reporting.API\Program.cs:line 19
```

My `Startup.cs` is pretty standard:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthentication();

    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseMvc();
}
```

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**:
i have removed `app.UseHttpsRedirection();` from Configure method.

For clarification purposes: **HTTPS Only** is set to true

[image]

Comment: Can't you just remove `app.UseHttpsRedirection();` and turn on HTTPS-only in the app service settings?

Comment: See also here https://hajekj.net/2018/09/07/usehttpsredirection-on-azure-app-service/

Comment: @silent thanks for the hint. Removed `app.UseHttpsRedirection();` and checked according the link you mentioned. But it didn't help

Comment: also set `ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT=443` didn't help

Comment: Look at this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-certificate-in-code

Comment: Or is it something very different? http://www.waynethompson.com.au/blog/dotnet-dev-certs-https/

Comment: The error talks about developer certs - maybe you actually need to set some env vars to tell you app it shouldnt run in debug/dev mode but in production?

Comment: @silent i think i will go for your last hint. That is what i also think is strange that it wants something with development. I will have a look. I also tried setting `WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES` with no success. Also tried `dotnet dev-certs https --clean` and `dotnet dev-certs https -t` which had an effect on my local machine but not in azure.

Comment: did you set this env? ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT (you should not set it, then it defaults to Production)

Comment: yes i setted this `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development` (in our development environment). I changed it to `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Staging` but with no effect.

Answer (score 0):

You could try configuring Kestrel to use your cert:

```
//**Program.cs :**
static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webHostBuilder =>
        {
            webHostBuilder.**UseKestrel**((builderContext, options) =>
            {
                options.Configure(builderContext.Configuration.**GetSection("Kestrel")**);
            });
        });

//**appsettings.json (or appsettings.development.json etc) :**    
"Kestrel": {
    "EndPoints": {
        "Http": {
            "Url": "http://yoursite.azurewebsites.net"
        },
      
        // Note: You most likely only need one of the following Https sections, thus only one is uncommented here...
        
        //"HttpsInlineCertFile": {
        //  "Url": "https://yoursite.azurewebsites.net:443",
        //  "Certificate": {
        //      "Subject": "YourCertName",
        //      "Store": "My", //"root",
        //      "Location": "LocalMachine", //"CurrentUser",
        //      "AllowInvalid": "True"
        //  }
        //}
        //"HttpsInlineCertStore": {
        //  "Url": "https://yoursite.azurewebsites.net:443",
        //  "Certificate": {
        //      "Subject": "YourCertName",
        //      "Store": "My", //"root",
        //      "Location": "LocalMachine", //"CurrentUser",
        //      "AllowInvalid": "True"
        //  }
        //}
        //"HttpsDefaultCert": {
        //  "Url": "https://yoursite.azurewebsites.net:443"
        //}
        "Https": {
            "Url": "https://*:443"
            "Certificate": {
            "Subject": "localhost",
            "Store": "My", //"root",
            "Location": "LocalMachine", //"CurrentUser",
            "AllowInvalid": "True"
            }
        }
    }
    // If using HttpsDefaultCert above, uncomment the following...
    //,
    //"Certificates": {
    //  "Default": {
    //    "Subject": "YourCertName",
    //    "Store": "My", //"root",
    //    "Location": "LocalMachine", //"CurrentUser",
    //    "AllowInvalid": true
    //  }
    //}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The editor asked me to generate the developer certificate using the below command

```
dotnet dev-certs https
```

To trust the developer certificate use the command

```
dotnet dev-certs https --trust
```

This helped me to run the application in the local. Please correct me know if this causes any issues.